# How to pre-populate a Matlab data store with timeseries data rather than just Initial Value

Tags: matlab, simulink, datastore

I have a Simulink model which requires the use of data store read/write blocks.
Normally, the read blocks will read from a data store that is being written-to from another part of the model.

However, for modular testing purposes, sometimes some of the data store write blocks are not available.
In this case, I would like to be able to pre-populate the data store with timeseries data for the whole simulation  (rather than just setting the initial value).
Note that I am creating the data store with Simulink.Signal objects in the base workspace (not using data store memory blocks)

I know that I could temporarily replace the data store read block with a block such as From Workspace.
However, this is not an ideal solution because it would be a very manual process to find and replace all of Data Store Read blocks back and forth between testing and production every time, and using variant switches or similar would add alot of clutter.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you create a harness for testing which uses `FromWorkspace` blocks to read in some pre-defined input data and pipe it straight into placeholder datastore write blocks, such that the datastore read blocks see no difference?

Comment: Hi Wolfie, thanks for your comment. Yes that is a possible solution and may be what is required if there are no alternatives. The main thing I dislike about it is that it creates an additional model that would require it's own upkeep.

Comment: You could write a function which creates this hardness dynamically by analysing your model and creating a subsystem with the relevant `FromWorkspace` and datastore write blocks in linked pairs, which would minimise upkeep. Agreed it wouldn't be ideal